# How to remote control the entire Android screen with AccessibilityService

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I want to remote control the entire Android screen with GestureDescription.StrokeDescription of the AccessibilityService API, but currently I can only touch a part of the screen.

[android screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDvmN.png)

Only the area of the red frame part of the attached image could be touched. Other areas, upper menu display and lower back, Home, Menu buttons cannot be pressed. The TeamViewer app can be operated remotely, but is it possible to implement a similar mechanism using only the Android SDK?

Comment: Please try asking your question in English.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The Japanese sentences are the same as the English sentences before machine translation, so there is no need to include them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.